# Can't see header in devtools for $http?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, http-headers

I can't see any data in the request header.

Using following

```
$http.post('http://localhost/api/validate', {}, { headers: key } );
```

[image]

form that is being passed in the run time is

[image]

Why am i unable to see any data set in header, inside the devtools. Getting null values on the server side as well.
Don't know what am i doing wrong.

After going through the comments and answers, I tried this, but still it doesn't work.

```
http.post('http://localhost/api/validate',key,
    { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'aplication/json'}}
}
```

Still getting the same results :(

As asked in the comments
Here is what it looks like in firefox
[image]

Comment: check the request payload.

Comment: Payload I can send, but as of now I want to send data in header.

Comment: Data in header can be sent in this format: {headers: {"key": "value"}} and it should be 2nd argument. the 1st argument is always payload or body

Comment: this is the format for a post request:

$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);

More details here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post

Comment: looking at your screenshot, I think that should be part of data (payload) and not headers

Comment: Can some one suggest how can i send it in header ?

Comment: The CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown. message is shown in DevTools because the headers you are seeing are not the actual headers sent to the server. In this case no headers were sent.

Answer (score 0):

The second arugument of POST call must be data object(PARAMS). I guess issue is because of that. And header should be: `{ headers: {key:value}`

```
$http.post('http://localhost/api/validate',{}, { headers: {key:value}} );
```

EX:

```
   $http.post("url", requestData, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'aplication/json'},

    }).success(function(responseData) {
        //do stuff with response
    });
```

Edit:

> The CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown. message is shown in
>   DevTools because the headers you are seeing are not the actual headers
>   sent to the server.

**Sometimes it's the AdBlock interfering, try disabling it if you have one and retry.**

Comment: @AnkurMarwaha check mu updates. Try similar approach.

Comment: @AnkurMarwaha Read all the response carefully and implement the changes properly. As Ved mentioned your header is still wrong. You can not assign a string value to header. You need to assign object to it.

Comment: still getting the same result, you can go through the edited question.

Comment: @AnkurMarwaha : The CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown. message is shown in DevTools because the headers you are seeing are not the actual headers sent to the server.

Comment: i guess for sending data in the header I need to submit the form or something like that and this $http wont help.

Comment: @AnkurMarwaha if you know the issue. Than solution is easy.

Comment: I don't know the issue. :(

Comment: @AnkurMarwaha can you test in MOZILA? Let me know if working or not.

Comment: Added screenshot for firefox.